# Proof by natural deduction advice

Tags: symbolic-logic

Any advice on shortening my right to left proof will be appreciated.

[image: Solution]

Comment: You can use disjunction elimination to derive `A v B`. Get `A -> (A v B)` and `(B & C) -> (A v B)` for that. Then derive `A v C` in a similar way. The proof should be a lot shorter.

Comment: This is math problem. And shouldn't be in this forum.

Comment: I am in a symbolic logic philosophy class and this is homework from that class.

Comment: This topic is in an overlap of mathematics and philosophy, so it is quite reasonable that it is tagged here.  On the other hand, asking at mathematics.stackexchange.com will have the advantage of the mathjax environment being available to typeset math questions and answers.

Comment: Have you had any success in applying the advice?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is valid but rather difficult to follow.  It is quite disorganised.

It would be clearer to collate the contexts together so that the reader does not have to track back and forth.

(I also prefer using just one disjunction elimination, although using two is not wrong.)

```
| _ 1 ( 1) A v (B & C)         P
||  2 ( 2) A                   H
||  2 ( 3) A v B              vI 2
||  2 ( 4) A v C              vI 2
||_ 2 ( 5) (A v B) & (A v C)  &I 3,4
||  3 ( 6) B & C               H
||  3 ( 7) B                  &E 6
||  3 ( 8) A v B              vI 7
||  3 ( 9) C                  &E 6
||  3 (10) A v C              vI 9
||_ 3 (11) (A v B) & (A v C)  &I 8,10
|   1 (12) (A v B) & (A v C)  vE 1,2..5,6..11
```

---

There is no need to use indirect proofs for the converse.  Nesting proofs by cases will suffice, since the premise simplifies into two disjunctions wit a common disjunct.

Here is a skeleton for you to fill out.  It should be clear what three hypothecia are needed, and how to derive the goal from them.

```
|   1   ( 1) (A v B) & (A v C)   P
|   1   ( 2) A v B              &E 1
| _ 1   ( 3) A v C              &E 1
||  2   ( 4)                     H
||_ 2   ( 5)                     
|| _3   ( 6)                     H
||| 4   ( 7)                     H
||| 3,4 ( 8)                     
|||_3,4 ( 9)           
||_ 3   (10) A v (B & C)        vE 3,4..5,7..9
|   1   (11) A v (B & C)        vE 2,4..5,6..10
```